# To form the group according to the requirements. From VGT by Nathan Carter

Tags: group-theory

[image]

Now for c) i think of a set with permutations on $a,b,c$. The three actions can be $f_1$= swapping first and second number. $f_2$= swapping second and third number and $f_3$ means swap of third and first number. But i am not sure

Comment: Please avoid pictures of text. They are difficult to search for and not every device renders them.

Comment: thats is why i mention book name and question in title

Comment: Fair enough $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples that fit the criteria.  Hopefully you'll be able to justify to yourself that these indeed work.

- (a): Take your actions to be all possible permutations on the letters $a,b,c$.
- (b): Take your actions to be all possible permutations on the letters $a,b$ (so either we swap or we do nothing)
- (c): Our object will be an equilateral triangle with one corner pointing upwards.  Take your actions to be the rotations that result in the triangle still pointing upwards.
- (d): The same as (c), but with a square.
- (e): Consider all possible rotations of a circle. Another example is all possible translations of an object along the number-line.

Your example for (c) does not work since it is not qualify as a group.  Note that (following rule 1.5) your list of actions is $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$.  With this setup, we don't satisfy rule 1.8, that every sequence of consecutive actions is also an action (in more conventional terminology, we would say that your set fails to be closed under composition, which is your set's binary operation).  In particular, consider the effect of applying $f_1$ then $f_2$.
$$
(a,b,c) \overset{f_1}\to (b,a,c) \overset{f_2}\to (b,c,a).
$$
The cyclic permutation $(a,b,c) \to (b,c,a)$ is not on our list of actions.

Note that if we were to make a group by filling in your list with all possible outcomes (i.e. if we were to consider the group "generated by" the elements $f_1,f_2,f_3$), then we would end up with the answer that I gave for (a).

Comment: {$f_1,f_2,f_3,f_1f_2,f_2f_1,e$} covers all permutations. am i missing something ?

Comment: @ConfusedSimpleton Yes, that covers all permutations

Comment: any composition of these three generators will also be among the above set i mentioned, no ?

Comment: @ConfusedSimpleton Yes that is correct

Comment: Then why does this not form a group ?

Comment: The set $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_1f_2,f_2f_1,e\}$ forms a group that contains six elements.  Your list $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$, however, does not form a group.  Your group, by definition, must consist of the entire list of possible actions.

Comment: the list {$f_1, f_2, f_3$} are the actions (generators) for the group of the 6 elements

Comment: If $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is your entire set of actions, then your set fails the requirement that "any sequence of consecutive actions is also an action", as I've stated in my answer.

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding of terminology. The set {$f_1,f_2,f_3$} is set of generators (aka actions) for the group {$f_1,f_2,f_3,...$}

Comment: Yes, there is a misunderstanding.  The "actions" referred to in the text are arbitrary group elements.  If we were to interpret "actions" as "generators", then rule 1.8 would mean "any product of generators is also a generator", which need not be true and is not true here.

Comment: Oh Ok so actions are elements of the group and not generators. Thats where i messed up

Comment: For c). Are you referring to $D_3$ group ? What rotations elsewise ?

Comment: @ConfusedSimpleton no, $D_3$ includes reflections.  This one only has rotations. It is a *subgroup* of $D_3$, though

Comment: So is it the rotations of $120$ and $240$ and $e$? but isnot it the same as the permutations of 3 numbers we discussed above

Comment: It is not.  If I combine any of the rotations from the list, then I will get one of the rotations from the list, which was not the case with your list of swaps.

Comment: The Cayley diagram for the c) as you said will be 3 nodes and for each node one 240 arrow will go out and 120 arrow will come in.

Comment: 4 arrows actually, 2 will go out and 2 will go in

Comment: Or it maybe a cyclic group kind of Cayley diagram with three nodes as $e, r$ and $r^2$